# My ida.reg file got deleted, is there any way to restore ida?

Tags: ida, idapython

I Got IDA Pro license and for some reason ida.reg file from my home/.ida directory got deleted and now I just can't run ida and instead I get following displayed -

[image]

Is there any way to restore ida? Unfortunately, my support is expired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately it reappeared once I open ida64 in GUI mode!